# Cant submit Angularjs cascading dropdown values with ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this cascading dropdowns in angular working with ng-options, but noticed the values are objects and wont pass through to db. Dont know if values have to be set explicitly like ng-repeat.

```
select#manufacturer.form-control(name="manufacturer", ng-model="listing.manufacturer", ng-options="c.make for c in carData")
    option(value="") Choose manufacturer

select#model.form-control(name="model", ng-model="listing.model", ng-disabled="!listing.manufacturer", ng-options="d.model for d in listing.manufacturer.models")
    option(value="") Choose model
```

data

```
$scope.carData = [
        {make: "Audi", models: [{ model: 'A1' }, { model: 'A2'}] }, {make: "BMW", models: [{ model: '316i' }, { model: '318i'}] }];
```

console view

```
<option value="object:3" label="Audi">Audi</option>
<option value="object:4" label="BMW">BMW</option>
```

help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT 2

----listing.js----

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Listing', new mongoose.Schema({
  manufacturer: String,
  model: String
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what's your problem with the object you're sending to the db.
But you could probably remove the models array from `listing.manufacturer`.

Please have a look at the demo below or in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/knyzb8tx/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
    .controller('mainController', MainController);

function MainController($scope, $window) {
    $scope.carData = [{
        make: "Audi",
        models: [{
            model: 'A1'
        }, {
            model: 'A2'
        }]
    }, {
        make: "BMW",
        models: [{
            model: '316i'
        }, {
            model: '318i'
        }]
    }];
    
    $scope.submit = function(formData) {
        delete formData.manufacturer.models; // remove not needed prop.
     $window.alert('send this data to your backend: ' + JSON.stringify(formData));
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <form ng-submit="submit(listing)">
    <select id="manufacturer" name="manufacturer" ng-model="listing.manufacturer" ng-options="c.make for c in carData" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Choose manufacturer</option>
    </select>
    <select id="model" name="model" ng-model="listing.model" ng-disabled="!listing.manufacturer" ng-options="d.model for d in listing.manufacturer.models" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Choose model</option>
    </select>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Update 06.09.2015**

So I created a demo as an exercise and found these points that are probably your problem (it's hard to tell because you haven't posted any backend code except mongoose schema):

- your mongoose schema have to match your data you're passing with ajax. So your model schema should be like this (required is optional and could be removed):

  ```
  new Schema({
      manufacturer: {
          make: {
              type: String,
              required: true
          }
      },
      model: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
      }
  });
  ```
- Also add `as d.model` to your model dropdown to remove the nested object then the second dropdown markup is like this (you can test this with an open browser console and check the error in the response from backend with-out the `as d.model`):

  ```
  <select id="model" name="model" 
      ng-model="listing.model" ng-disabled="!listing.manufacturer" 
      ng-options="d.model as d.model for d in listing.manufacturer.models" class="form-control">
  ```
- Create a copy of the new data in the submit method to avoid deletion of form model data. Not really a problem but a bug in my code above.

You can get my code at [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/awolf2904/mongoose-angular-demo). Clone it and it should help you getting started with mongoose.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I think the form is sending an object but the listing model is expecting a string. It isint throwing any error, but it just wont persist the whole listing model on submit. Is there a way I send a string from the form or should I be doing the conversion in the model? Ive added a snipet of the model in my originial post.

Comment: Above mentioned listing model is "listing.js", just in case not to confuse with the model field on form.